# Resize QDialog to fit mult-monitor display

Tags: python, pyside

How can i adjust my dialog to make it support multi monitor setups? in Pyside using python 2.7 on windows.

```
import os, sys, re, pprint
sys.path.append(os.environ.get('PS_SITEPACKAGES'))

from Qt import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui


class MonsterScreen(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MonsterScreen, self).__init__()
        self.img = None

        # get screen size
        print QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry()
        print QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
        self.sizes = []
        for i in range(QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().screenCount()):
            self.sizes.append(QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry(i))
        self.width, self.height = self.sizes[0].width(), self.sizes[0].height()

        totalSize = QtCore.QRect(0,0,0,0)
        for x in self.sizes:
            totalSize = totalSize.united(x)
        self.resize(totalSize.size())
        print self.sizes
        print totalSize


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MonsterScreen()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: use `win.showFullScreen()`

Comment: That only makes the application full screen on a single window. i want it to span all monitors.

Comment: Similar to how windows Snippet tool when you launch it, will span all monitors with a white opacity of 30%

Comment: Mmm, I had misunderstood. I think that this task should be done by an OS configuration, maybe I am wrong.